# Selection of the maximum deleted_data from duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Table structure:

[image]

It is not possible to select records with the maximum delete date, which are grouped by one code, with the condition that they are all deleted. If the records have the same code, but have different delete statuses, then you do not need to select these records.
In this example, you select records with id = 3, id = 4.

```
SELECT * FROM analyzes_test WHERE code IN (SELECT code FROM analyzes_test GROUP BY code HAVING count(code)>1) AND deleted = (max deleted_date)
```

But I do not know how to substitute the longest possible date for deletion.
Please tell me who has more experience with sql.

Answer (score 0):

you could use  an inner join on max date group by code

```
select * 
FROM analyzes_test a
inner join  (
  select code, max(deleted_date) max_date 
  FROM analyzes_test 
  group by code  
)  t on t.max_date = a.deleted_date and t.code = a.code
```

or if you don't want thw result for code with only a rows  a could use

```
select * 
FROM analyzes_test a
inner join  (
  select code, max(deleted_date) max_date 
  FROM analyzes_test 
  group by code  
  having count(*)>1
)  t on t.max_date = a.deleted_date and t.code = a.code
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:** `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` will help to retrieve the max date of each code and use it as a `subquery` to retrieve all the information for the table as below:

```
SELECT ant.* 
FROM analyzes_test ant
INNER JOIN (SELECT code, MAX(deleted_date) max_date 
        FROM analyzes_test 
        WHERE deleted_date IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY code
        HAVING COUNT(deleted_date) > 1) t ON t.code = ant.code 
    AND t.max_date = ant.deleted_date
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the id of the data records?

Comment: I need to pull out all the information about these records

Answer (score 0):

Try the following simple query-:

```
select code,max(deleted_date) MAX_DeletedDate
  from analyzes_test  
group by code 
  having count(deleted_date)>1
```